# Map a collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

I have two tables:

```
Table_A (Id1 PK, Id2)

Table_B (Id1 PK, Id2 PK, Id3 PK)
```

**Goal:**

Map to `NHibernate` set of rows from `table_b` as a collection in `table_a` object

```
<set name="Table_B_elements" table="Table_B" lazy="true">
                <key columns="Id1"/>
                <one-to-many class="Handler"/>
</set>
```

I can easily make a query like

```
select *
from Table_A as a
join Table_B as b on b.Id1 = a.Id2;
```

Any suggestions how to map it?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Read http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-join or here http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping depending on what you really want to select.
These are absolute basics for nHibernate. I would suggest first reading docs, then asking.

Comment: I've read docs first of all, notice that problem is in complex keys in Table_B. If you have an opportunity to explain it - do it